# Android -- Getting a callback when the keyboard is dismissed using the hardware back button

Tags: android, keyboard, back, dismiss

I'm launching the keyboard this way:

```
    InputMethodManager inputMethodService = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodService != null && inputMethodService.isActive()) {
        inputMethodService.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    }
```

I'm capturing "done" this way:

```
   editField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The above method does not fire when the hardware back button is clicked. How do I capture it?

EDIT: I've tried `onBackPressed()`, `onResume()`, `onKeyDown()` and `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Are you sure that your `onKeyDown()` method never gets called with your hardware keyboard?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to do validation on the `EditText`